# FancyBox 2.0 afterClose event

Tags: fancybox, jquery

I have script fancybox like this

```
$.fancybox.open({
                href : '<?= site_url('sell_split/popup_qty/') ?>'+url_param,
                type : 'ajax',
                afterShow: popup_focus_qty,
                afterClose: console.log('test')
            });
```

As you can see, there is `afterClose` event. But it seems when i try this script the `afterClose` event is happened first and then `GET` process.

[image]

This is not what i want.
What i want to do is, the event `afterClose` is happening if the visitor closed FancyBox Window.

Is this an error from FancyBox plugin or the my code is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i found the answer myself, it should written like this

```
$.fancybox.open({
            href : '<?= site_url('sell_split/popup_qty/') ?>'+url_param,
            type : 'ajax',
            afterShow: popup_focus_qty,
            afterClose: function(){
                console.log('test')
            }                
        });
```